# Break URL into parts and locate the ID (longest part)

Tags: php, regex

I have a URL:

```
$url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ljJpZDiayzMLhIJ-JDSIJjdjdY_xg3RrUDljFVRB0Qk/edit?usp=sharing#helloworld';
```

I want to get the ID out of this URL. The ID is *always* the longest part of the URL `1ljJpZDiayzMLhIJ-JDSIJjdjdY_xg3RrUDljFVRB0Qk`, so my approach is to target the longest part.

How can I break this URL into parts and grab the longest part? I want to ignore the query variable part `?usp=sharing#helloworld` when breaking it into parts.

### What I've tried so far

I tried a `preg_match_all()` approach with a regex that doesn't seem to break the URL properly:

```
$regex = '/^(([^:\/?#]+):)?(\/\/([^\/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?/';
$url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ljJpZDiayzMLhIJ-JDSIJjdjdY_xg3RrUDljFVRB0Qk/edit?usp=sharing#helloworld';
$result = preg_match_all($regex, $url, $matches);
print($matches);
```

Comment: remove `https://docs.google.com/` using `str_replace` and explode the string by "/" and find the index where your id is stored.

Comment: `parse_url()` and / or `explode()`.

Comment: Avoid regex as much as possible. Split URL with `/` and find longest string in array -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/3713517

Comment: @hjpotter92 Sounds viable, but I want to ignore the `?usp=sharing#helloworld` part because occasionally, it is longer than the ID. Please feel free to post an answer.

Comment: @hungrykoala The URL doesn't always start with `https://docs.google.com/` -- it was only an example.

Comment: @jeroen Please feel free to post an answer. Note that `https://docs.google.com/` may be different sometimes and query variable `?usp=sharing#helloworld` needs to be removed when checking the longest part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the function `explode` to split a string in a array.

And the function `parse_url()`to get the path of your URL.

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$array = explode("/", $path);
```

---

**edit**

If you want to include query-variables you can add this three lines.

```
parse_str($query,$queries);
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$array = array_merge($array, $queries);
```

---

Now you can look wich part is the longest.

```
$id = "";
foreach($array as $part){
    if(strlen($id) < strlen($part)) {
        $id = $part;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is excellent, but it doesn't seem to work this with type of URLs: `https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ljJpZDiayzMLhTZcywUGyVkC2Y_xg3RrUDljFVRB0Qggk`

Comment: I have add a few lines to include the query in the search.

Comment: Thank you! This is the one.

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ljJpZDiayzMLhIJ-JDSIJjdjdY_xg3RrUDljFVRB0Qk/edit?usp=sharing#helloworld';
$partURL=explode('/', $url);
$lengths = array_map('strlen', $partURL);
$maxLength = max($lengths);
$index = array_search($maxLength, $lengths);
echo $partURL[$index];
```

**Returns**: `1ljJpZDiayzMLhIJ-JDSIJjdjdY_xg3RrUDljFVRB0Qk`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex: `^.*\/d\/(.*)\/.*$`
For example:

```
$regex = '/^.*\/d\/(.*)\/.*$/';
$url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ljJpZDiayzMLhIJ-JDSIJjdjdY_xg3RrUDljFVRB0Qk/edit?usp=sharing#helloworld';
$result = preg_match_all($regex, $url, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

in result you'll have:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ljJpZDiayzMLhIJ-JDSIJjdjdY_xg3RrUDljFVRB0Qk/edit?usp=sharing#helloworld
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1ljJpZDiayzMLhIJ-JDSIJjdjdY_xg3RrUDljFVRB0Qk
        )

)
```

Comment: This doesn't work with all URLs. For example `https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ljJpZDiayzMLhTZcywUGyVkC2Y_xg3RrUDljFVRB0Qkss2` Therefore, I need to break the URL in parts, no matter its setup first, and then grab the longest part (ignoring the query variable).

Comment: @GoodbyeWorld you can't ignore query part in second example, because id is a part of query. You need to specify types of links and use different parsers for different url types.

Answer (score 0):

you can use substr(string,start,length)

Comment: Elaborate please.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter parse_url result with PHP_URL_QUERY, for example

```
$query = parse_url(<url string>, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($parts, $queryArray);
$queryArray[<KEY>]
```